# Get Windows "load average" in Java

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface

I'm currently writing a Java application that needs to look at how "heavily loaded" the machine it's running on is. On *nix, load average divided by number of processors fits the bill perfectly, and we retrieve load average with `ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getSystemLoadAverage()`. Unfortunately, this returns -1 on Windows, as the call is apparently too "expensive" to be called frequently. What's the easiest way to retrieve similar Windows metrics such as the processor queue length or CPU utilisation, either in pure Java or via JNI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the CPU utilization on Windows using WMI. Some code and documentation for accessing WMI from Java appears to be available [here](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/other_examples/WMI_Scripting_from_Java.htm).

Comment: Or even easier, use the wmic interface!

Comment: I've always been a fan of do it in code over invoking an external program, but wmic seems useful.

Comment: WMI looks like what I'm after. I don't think I'll go down the J-Integra route, though - I'm thinking of using code from http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/ , although I'm still on the lookout for something that calls it programatically (this one creates a VBScript dynamically).

Comment: @Anders, could you please show me how to do it? J-integra is not free software.

Comment: @eric2323223 `wmic` is a native Windows scripting interface for WMI (if WMI exists on a host - so does `wmic`), just invoke it through your Java application.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the free Hyper SIGAR API.  It is a cross platform API for calling system information.  It uses JNI for Windows/Linux/Unix/Mac/etc.

http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar

I wrote a JNLP task manager/information monitor with it and it's a decent API.

http://www.goliathdesigns.com/2009/12/sixth-post/

Source code:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sysinfomonitor/

Answer (score 0):

You can also perfom this task using Eclipse SWT if you are running on an win32 environment:

http://dentrassi.de/2011/02/04/access-to-wmi-in-java-using-eclipse-swt-ole-integration/